# Displaying images from mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display images on my view from mysql path.
In my mysql table i have row called imgpath  and the file location is assets/images/acura_1.jpg
It's displaying the car information correctly from the table but the actual image is not showing up?  Thanks!

Here is my code in the view

```
 <h1>Our Current Cars:</h1>
                    <?php foreach($images as $row)
                    {

                        echo "<br/>";
                    ?> <img src = <?php echo $row->imgpath; ?> >
                    <?php "<br/> ";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<font color = 'red'>";

echo $row->car_year . " " . $row->car_make . " " . $row->car_model . "<br/>";
echo "Lease Term: " . $row->car_lease . " Months" . "<br/>";
echo "Base Payment: " . "$" . $row->car_payment . "<br/>" ;
echo "</font>";
}

                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you are not in the root of the web-site and the `/assets` folder is.

You can use absolute paths for your images:

```
<img src = "/<?php echo $row->imgpath; ?>" >
            ^ here
```

If some images might start with a slash, you could use `ltrim` to get rid of them:

```
<img src = "/<?php echo ltrim($row->imgpath, '/'); ?>" >
```

Comment: I edit it to <img src = "/<?php echo $row->imgpath; ?>/" > and its not working.  BTW I am assets/images directory is in the root outside of the Application folder.

Comment: I tried this <img src = "/<?php echo ltrim($row->imgpath, '/'); ?>" >  its still not working.

Comment: This is my html in my view <img src = "/<?php echo ltrim($row->imgpath, '/'); ?>" >  is this what you mean?

Comment: @Masoman No, what is the html when you look at the source in your browser?

Comment: <h1>Our Current Cars:</h1>
<br/> <img src = "/assets/images/acura_1.jpg" >

Comment: thats what it should be assets/images/accura_1.jpg.   Outside of the Application folder I have assets/images/accura_1.jpg

Comment: when i copy the URL image that does not show it shows http://localhost/assets/images/acura_1.jpg.  It cannot be found because it should be http://localhost/redline/assets/images/acura_1.jpg (REAL IMAGE PATH)

Comment: @Masoman I don't know where `redline` comes from all of a sudden, but if all images are located there, you should use: `<img src = "/redline/<?php echo ltrim($row->imgpath, '/'); ?>" >`

Comment: it worked!  I had to put /redline/  which is my root folder name, thank you!